# What is the Android version that supports jvmTarget 1.8?

Tags: android, jvm

To fix a compatibility problem in my Android app I've just changed in my `build.gradle` file the target version of JVM and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk` from `7` to `8`

```
android {
    ......
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
   ....
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
   ....
}
```

Now my project is compiled to JVM 8 and I'm asking myself a question on what minimum Android Api this JVM 8 is supported. I suppose that after this change some old devices cannot execute my app.

My minimum Android API is 21. I ran my app at emulator and it seems to be ok.

Could somebody tell me if all devices from this version supports JVM 8 or by this simple change I can introduce a lot of surprises later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Android API 19, it can support JVM 8 but not fully (for SDK 19). 
Your PC should has Android Studio 3+ and JDK 8 installed to compile it. 
Your android device has nothing to do with Java versions, it will support what its android API supports. 
BUT you need to be careful, Android API doesn't support all what JDK 8 supports, even for some semi modern APIs like 25! 
For example: Some Cipher padding and hashes are supported in JDK 8 but not in Android API 25.

SO, in your case, you should check what Android API 21 supports not JDK 8 or even 7 does.